# adjective for a success in the growth of freedoms of citizens in a country

Tags: word-request, adjectives

If financial situation of citizens is growing, we would call it economic success in the country.

If the population is growing, we call it a demographic success.

What if citizens' freedoms (like freedom of speech, of travelling, of religion, etc.) are growing, how would we describe that success?

(I need an adjective).

EDIT:

Some confusion took place in comments, so, to avoid any further confusion:

1. Just like in case with economic success and demographic success, I am looking for an adjective that would describe/modify the word “success”;
2. I need to keep the word “success” – it’s crucial;
3. Adjectives containing hyphens or spaces are also welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The requirements of the question are:

- an adjective that describes “freedom” or “liberty”
- the word **success**

This is very difficult.

## Not every noun in English has a good adjective form.

Some nouns have good adjectives:

> economics — economic (or economical)
>
> ecology — ecological
>
> trees — arboreal
>
> cows — bovine
>
> pigs — porcine
>
> freedom — free
>
> democracy — democratic

But many don’t.

> civil liberty — civil-libertarian? **Liberational**? *No.*

## “Success” might not be the best word to describe this

Success is a word that describes both “pass/fail” concepts and a *gradient* (continuum).

Democracy, civil liberties and related ideas exist on a continuum.

There is no *perfect* level of civil liberties or 100% democracy.

You have more flexibility if you use words like “improvement” or “increase”.

## Possible answers

These might be close:

> Maybe: *The society’s libertarian success*
>
> Maybe: *The society’s democratic success*
>
> Maybe: *The society’s human rights success*

But why not:

> Better:  **The society’s level of human rights success**
>
> Better:  **The society’s increasing human rights success**

You can also do a **compound noun** instead of an *adjective plus noun*, but this can be quite ugly:

> Use with caution:
>
> - the society’s civil liberties success;
> - the society’s democracy success;
> - the society’s ballot access success

This kind of writing feels very technical. English is open to compound nouns but this can sound very strange.

## Or just say what you mean:

I’d recommend you give up on”xxx success” and rephrase.

> Best:  **The society’s recent improvement in civil liberties, access to the ballot box, a free press, freedom of worship, and economic opportunity...**

Or just as good:

> Best:  **The society’s success at improving human rights and democratic conditions**

Or whatever.

Bottom line:  **you may not be able to force the sentence to say** “xxx success”, since not every concept can be expressed that way.

Comment: "Success is a word that describes both “pass/fail” concepts and a gradient (continuum)"  - Can you, please, elaborate here? I don't quiet understand the point being made. (An example of "success" as a pass as opposed to and example of "success" as continuum might help me here).

Comment: Your question states "If the population is growing, we call it a demographic success."  **I don't think this premise is true.**  It's not clear from your question ***why*** you are insisting the answer must have the word "success".  Political scientists generally **don't** use the word **success** in describing a society's civil liberties, because they recognize a range of conditions, for example in restrictions on the press -- even in "open" societies -- for which there is no **perfect exemplar** that exists, nor a consensus on what "success" consists of.

Comment: I understand that. But can you, please, explain or give an example of how the word "success" can describe a continuum - that was the point that I didn't understand. Webster gives two definitions for "continuum": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/continuum . Which one do you mean, the first one or the second one?

Comment: The first one, with the example "a continuum of temperatures ranging from very cold to very hot".

Answer (score 1):

An increase in peoples **Civic Freedoms and/or Liberties**.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need. I need an adjective. Precisely, an adjective that would go along with the word "success".

Comment: [**emancipation**](https://www.synonyms.com/synonym/Emancipation) (noun) - *freeing someone from the control of another*. Although with the increasing instability associated with "populism" (and sometimes ill-informed voters / protesters), not every social commentator would necessarily enthuse over the "successful" democratization / Westernization of the world.

Comment: A "Sociological Success" ?

Comment: @brilliant The word *increase* fits without a problem. The adjectival form of *increase* is *increasing*. So: ***increasing*** *success*.

Comment: @JasonBassford - AFAIK, the word _increasing_ does not contain any civic-freedom connotation.

Comment: @rkchl - Yes, I think "sociological" would be the answer. If a native speaker heard "sociological success", what would be his immediate idea (or association) in his mind?

Comment: @JasonBassford - “It doesn't have to, because it precedes freedom of speech”
- I need an adjective that precedes the word “success”, instead. 
“If you're looking for an adjective that means both growing and civic freedom”
- I don’t need the adjective to mean “growing” – the connotation of having some amount of satisfactory growth of something is already conveyed by the word “success” that will follow right after the adjective. So, I only need a civic-freedom meaning adjective. 
“... sociological means neither growing nor civic freedom” 
- It’s a new word for me. I know nothing about it.

Comment: @JasonBassford (1) “The word success in no way implies growth” 
– It does imply some kind of increase that has transpired, which is already enough for me. 

“My speech was a success. There is no growth involved there”
– It all depends on how you look at it. Before my speech, the level of appreciation from the audience that I enjoyed was close to zero. Now it’s almost 7 on 10-point scale. It’s definitely a good increase for me! I am growing as a speaker!

Comment: @JasonBassford (2) But why talk about the concepts of growth and increase in the first place??? I already have a noun “success” in my question and I need to keep it, not replace it! Somehow in this answer this word was replaced with “increase”. And later you and I started talking about increase and growth. But that’s not what I need. Whatever the connotations of “success” are (be it growth and increase or just achievement, attainment, advancement in something, etc.), it all suffice for me. What I really need, though, is the civic-freedom meaning adjective that would modify the word “success”.

Comment: @JasonBassford (3) “Also, if you don't know anything about the word sociological, I'm very confused by your earlier comment saying you thought it was the answer”

– The answer is hidden in your question. Precisely, in the word “thought”. In my reply to supporter rkchl I said, “Yes, I think that would be the answer”. I never said something like, “I am sure/ I know this is the answer!” or “Yes! This is the answer!”

Comment: @JasonBassford (4) Besides, unlike in his answer, this was his first attempt to modify “success” rather than replace it. Hence, unlike “An increase in peoples Civic Freedoms”, the “sociological success” was more like an answer to my actual request.

Comment: @JasonBassford - (1) “You yourself use growth in your question. If fact, you use it three times”
- Yes, and all three times the word “growth” appeared in the if-clause of each of the three sentences in my question, whereas in the end of each three sentences the word “success” appeared (take, for example, the second sentence: “If the population is growing, we call it a demographic success.”) In all three sentences the word “success” was the one to be described. Read my very question in the last sentence one more time: “… how would you describe that success?”

Comment: @JasonBassford - (2) In the first sentence it was the adjective “economic” as an example. In the second, the adjective “demographic”. So, in the third sentence I was simply requesting another adjective to describe “success” again – except this time in the context of civic freedoms. Neither “economic”, nor “demographic” in my previous two examples convey the notion of some increase, or growth, or some positive change, etc. All of those connotations, if any, were concealed in the word “success” instead.

Comment: @JasonBassford - (3) On the other hand, “increasing success” would absolutely NOT be the answer to my question because the adjective “increasing” doesn’t have a connotation of civic freedoms at all.

Comment: @JasonBassford - (4) The phrase “An increase in peoples Civic Freedoms” may be pertinent to what I ask; however, it’s NOT what I ask for because there is no adjective in it (while I requested an adjective) and it doesn’t describe the word “success” (it is not even found in that phrase).

Answer (score 0):

> Social-liberty-success
>
> Or
>
> Societal-autonomy-success
>
> Or
>
> Liberal-life-success

Answer (score 0):

Fully agreed to WhiskeyChief but I see that the answer still does not satisfy you so I'm ***forced*** to come up with something that is *not usual.*

You are searching for a five-legged elephant. As FumbleFingers suggested, you need a different *verb* to express the success of 'so-called' growth in freedom.

*Forcefully,* you may opt for *liberty* rather than freedom in this case. Since you are *stuck* to the word **success** at any cost, it could be...

> ***A nation's liberation success depends on ...***

Comment: Thanks for the effort done within the requirements stated in the question. Can you, please, tell me: would such phrase as "nation's liberation success" first cause a native speaker think of a freedom that one nation gets (say, as a result of an independence war, in which the nation stops being a part of another nation) or of a freedom (like human-rights freedom) that citizens pertaining to one nation enjoy within it?

Comment: It depends on the context. If you write *A nation's liberation success depends on the Human Development Index* then it relates to the 'happiness' of the citizen and quality of their lives. But, by large, liberty would come with human rights freedoms as stated in the question, IMO.

Comment: I have yet to see an answer in the form of “xxx success” that would not earn a mark in red pen from my high school English teachers as being “awkward— rephrase.”   The question is overly restrictive to be able to provide an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

> **If financial situation of citizens is growing, we would call it economic success in the country. If the population is growing, we call it a demographic success.
>   What if citizens' freedoms (like freedom of speech, of travelling, of religion, etc.) are growing, how would we describe that success?**

**Enhanced Civic Entitlements** or **Enhanced Civic Liberties**

Try this "**In our lifetime, Our Nation has seen a Prosperous Economy, Demographic Success and the People's Civic Liberties Enhanced"**

> **enhanced**; adjective: [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enhanced) better than before: greater in value than before:
>
> We continue to create new and enhanced versions of our products.
>
> The measures to encourage investment include enhanced capital allowances.
>
> **civic**: adjective: before noun); [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/civic) of a town or city or the people who live in it:
>
> **entitlement**; noun [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/entitlement?q=Entitlement)  LAW, HR a situation in which you have the right to do or have something:
>
> **liberty** noun (Freedom) [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/liberty?q=Liberty) :formal the freedom to live as you wish or go where you want:

Comment: I realise I can write  "In our lifetime, Our Nation has seen a Prosperous Economy, Demographic Success and Civic Liberties Enhanced" and it would have the same meaning I have included "the people's" for clarity. As political statements often do.